# how to check activities lifecycle state in Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want to work on my data depending on what Lifecycle state I have.

For example, I want to do something, when the application was resumed.
How can I find out in what State is my app now?
Thanks for help.

Comment: `I want to do smth, when application was resumed` - put that code in the callback then?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 17):

in activity: `if (getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) ...` I think. If you're asking about async tasks.

Answer (score 0):

For custom class you can use lifecycle from architecture components, first add library

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

then your custom class, for example

```
public class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void connectListener() {
        ...
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void disconnectListener() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and finally from your lifecycle container (activity/fragment)

```
myActivity.getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyObserver());
```

More info here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

Comment: They actually made a library for this!

Answer (score 0):

There are predefined methods of an Activity.
Please review Life cycle of an Activity in Android.

Example code

```
public class LifeCycleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON CREATE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onStart(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onResume(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON RESUME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPause(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON PAUSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onRestart(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON RESTART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onStop(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDestroy(); 
        Toast.makeText(LifeCycleActivity.this,"ON DESTROY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

Also read: - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Are you reinventing Lifecycle.State? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State